# How to plot mulitple coulmns of a dataframe in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have asked this question several times but somehow my question has no views at all. I hope I have structured the question correctly this time.
I have a dataframe as below:

```
  indeces      Zeitstempel     Ergebnis
0   382    16.04.2020 16:12:07  PASS
1   383    16.04.2020 16:13:07  PASS
2   392    16.04.2020 16:13:20  FAIL
3   382    16.04.2020 16:13:22  PASS
4   383    16.04.2020 16:14:22  PASS
```

The dataframe has three columns. I am trying to build a graph where the x-axis is Zeitstempel(combo of date/time), y-axis is indeces and I would also want to specify the values of Ergebnis columns(color coding green for PASS,red for FAIL and grey for BLOCKED)
The graph should represent which indeces value is passing or failing or blocking at what Zeitstempel value. The actual dataframe has 1172 rows × 3 columns values but in the above I have only mentioned few.
The code I am trying is as below but somehow I am not able to figure out how to plot all the 3 as required.

```
# times = pd.date_range('2020-04-16 16:12 AM', '2020-04-16 11:00 PM', freq='1H')
# df["Zeitstempel"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Zeitstempel'],errors='coerce')
groups = df.groupby("Ergebnis")
marker = ["x","x","*"]
size = [15,5,2]
i = 0
#plt.subplots(311)
for name,group in groups:
  #plt.subplot(3,1,i+1)

  plt.plot(df["Zeitstempel"][:2],group["indeces"][:2],marker=marker[i],markersize = size[i],label=name)
  i = i + 1

plt.legend()
```

This is giving me a graph but it is in accurate. The reason I have mentioned [:2] is because it keeps throwing dimension errors. This is a line graph. I also tried with bar plots but no luck.
Could anyone suggest me what has to be actually done here to get the actual graph. I am stuck in this from days and unable to figure out what has to be done. I also tried the numpy array but since this is dataframe
I cannot use numpy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the ungrouped dataframe `df` in your loop. Try this:

```
dict_color = {
    'PASS': 'green',
    'FAIL': 'red',
    'BLOCKED': 'grey'
}
dict_marker = {
    'PASS': "x",
    'FAIL': "x",
    'BLOCKED': "*"
}
for ergebnis, df_small in df.groupby(['Ergebnis']):
    plt.scatter(
        x=df_small['Zeitstempel'], 
        y=df_small['indeces'],
        color=dict_color[ergebnis],
        marker=dict_marker[ergebnis],
        label=ergebnis
    )
plt.legend()
```